# When I Generate signed APK, I got an issue

Tags: android, gradle

I want to Generate signed APK, and I have compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'.
but It's happened some issue. It's looks like about "okhttp" issue.
I don't know how to resolve it. I research many info, but its seems seldom info about this.

Messages:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleFreeRelease]
Warning:okhttp3.Address: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Authenticator: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Cache: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Cache$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Cache$CacheResponseBody: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Cache$Entry: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.CacheControl: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.CertificatePinner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Challenge: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Connection: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.ConnectionPool: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.ConnectionSpec: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.ConnectionSpec$Builder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Cookie: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Dispatcher: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.FormBody: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Handshake: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Headers: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.HttpUrl: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.HttpUrl$Builder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Interceptor$Chain: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.MediaType: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.MultipartBody: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.MultipartBody$Builder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.MultipartBody$Part: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.OkHttpClient: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Request: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Request$Builder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.RequestBody: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.RequestBody$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.RequestBody$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.RequestBody$3: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Response: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Response$Builder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.ResponseBody: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.ResponseBody$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.Route: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.WebSocket: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheStrategy: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.internal.cache.DiskLruCache$Snapshot: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okhttp3.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
Warning:okio.AsyncTimeout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okio.Buffer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okio.BufferedSource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okio.ByteString: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.HashingSink: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio$4: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okio.RealBufferedSource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okio.Segment: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okio.SegmentPool: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:okio.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
Warning:there were 169 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForFreeRelease'. Job failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 9.693 secs
Information:1 error
Information:58 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

How can I resolve this issue??

Comment: check gradle console logs

Comment: delete all build Folder From Project And Then try To Generate Signed.

Answer (score 8):

it looks like `minifyEnabled` is set to true in your `build.gradle`
so it is applying proguard rules. so you should add this rules to your `proguard-rules.pro` file

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
```

Comment: I add your code into my proguard-rules.pro, and success solve my question, Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept @shmakova's answer or mine :)

Comment: @BillyLu if this answer or any other answer has helped you, you should accept it as answer by checking the gray check mark on the left of the question and turn it into green.

Answer (score 1):

I also face this error. I have fix by adding below code in proguard.

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp3.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp3.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add these lines to your proguard file:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.Nullable
-dontwarn javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
```

Comment: these three lines are getting removed automatically from my progaurd file while compiling. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

Possible that you're obfuscating your code, check your `build.gradle` file and make sure the parameter `minifyEnabled` is set to `false` in order to not obfuscate your code,

it should look something like this:

```
release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
...
        }
```

Compile and check if the problem is solved or not, and comment if you want to know more on obfuscation of android code.